# Why is the assertion not equal?

Tags: reactjs, chai

I am trying to test my react reducer with chai:

```
const initialState = {
    cartOpen: false
}

const Cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'INITIALIZE_CART':
           return 1

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
it('should return the initial state', () => {
    expect(
        reducer(undefined, {})
    ).to.equal(
        { cartOpen: false }
    )
})
```

I can't understand why I get this error:

```
cart reducer should return the initial state:                                                       

 AssertionError: expected { cartOpen: false } to equal { cartOpen: false }                          
 + expected - actual                                                                                


 at Context.<anonymous> (C:/Usersdevelop_5dec/foss/foss-frontend/test/cart.spec.js:11:14)
```

Looks like expected and actual are the same? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two different object references created in two different places. `.equal()` uses `===` under the hood, which compares references.

If you're using chai, you can use [`.deep`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep)

```
expect(
    reducer(undefined, {})
).to.deep.equal((
    { cartOpen: false }
)
```

Comment: Beat by "this much". I was going to suggest the similar, but alternate eql: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql